# Using C/C++ Library on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have coded a library that provides some function add, sub, divide, multi by c/c++ programming language. It's built to library.so by using Android NDK. So now, I want to call these function of library by using Android. I want to as How I can do ?

Thank.

Comment: You need to use jni functions/wrapper. This question has been asked many times. Did you do any research?

Comment: I got it now. I'm a newbee so there are many thing that need to improve. Thank for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-simple-way-to-write-C%2B%2B-codes-using-Android-Studio/answer/Mohan-Mohan-232?share=9e0367d0&srid=hnO3j).

**NDK Package**

Android Studio only includes the default tools and SDK, so download and install the NDK package separately. There are two ways to do this. The first and easiest is the automatic installation option in the SDK Tools tab. This is a large download (~1GB) so be sure to have a good internet connection and/or patience.

[image]

The second way is to download the NDK manually from the [NDK Downloads page](http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html). This saves some time because of the smaller download size (<.5 GB) but will need some setting up. Download the appropriate NDK package for your platform and follow the installation instructions. You can put the extracted package anywhere you want, but remember this location as you will need it later.

[image]

**Hello World**

Let’s run a test project to see if the NDK installation works. The NDK package folder contains samples but they don’t seem to work out of the box in Android Studio without extra configuration. Instead we’ll import samples that work from the welcome screen. These [NDK samples from GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk) can also be downloaded or cloned directly. This collection of samples has better compatibility with the latest version of Android Studio.

[image]

Select Import an Android code sample and type hello in the search box to filter the list. Choose Hello JNI from the filtered list under the Ndk category. Click Next to edit the app name and project location, then click Finish.

**JNI**

After the code has loaded and Gradle has synced, let’s take a look at the resulting project structure. You might have noticed what appears to be a discrepancy in the project’s name. Why is it called HelloJNI and not HelloNDK? What is ‘JNI’ and how does it differ from the ‘NDK’? The ‘Java Native Interface’ is a framework that enables Java applications to interact with native code. The JNI and the NDK work together to bring native support to Android apps. The NDK is part of the Android framework while the JNI is available to any Java application, not just Android apps.

Inside the project is a folder named jni which will hold all the native C or C++ source code of the app. The JNI provides a two-way interface. The C/C++ code is able to call Java code, including the standard Android libraries, and the Java code is able to call native functions defined in C/C++ code. Native code is governed by the same sandbox and security rules as Java code so the app will not have full unrestricted access to hardware. For a more detailed discussion on the JNI, read the JNI articles from the [Android Developer website](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html).

Comment: That's really good tutorial. Thank you. I wish I get it soon. I took a lot of time to investigation. There are many resources that make me confusion.

Comment: @SiddhantGhosh You ripped this answer directly from [HERE](http://qr.ae/TUIGFt) , you could at least have given credit or change the answer to your own words.

Answer (score 1):

For a working example project, you can find one from here: https://github.com/russell-shizhen/JniExample