# Android build c++ with dependency

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I am working on an Android application with NDK. My c++ code has some dependencies from c++ open source libraries, so I can download the source code of the dependencies and package them in my app. I have created my CMakeList files, but I don't know how to include the external library.

I would like to build the dependency to be able to use it in my own project, so the flow would be as follows:

1. cd external/library/path
2. ./configure
3. make
4. build my app and link the built dependency

Is this possible? If so, how can this be done? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new on C++ and Cmake.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51372902/8034839

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/a/52952274/8034839

Comment: Do I have to create a different project for each library and then link them to my main project?

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was by cross compiling the libraries and adding them as static libraries. You can cross compile using the clang binaries included in the ndk directory, using the one that targets your app min sdk.